# Testfor from player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This probably sounds like a bad question and I should know this, but how do you test for a block relative from a player? I put down a command block with "testfor ~1 ~ ~ " but that did it from the command block. (I expected it to with that) "testfor @a ~1 ~ ~ " didnt work, and neither did "testfor ~1 ~ ~  @a". What is the right way to write this?

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot use testfor to do this, you CAN use execute detect. This is most likely how it would look:  `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~1 ~ ~ grass 0 <command>`

the execute command will detect a grass block to the left (in the X cord) of all players in the world. the command is how you would track that player if it detects the block successfully.

an example tracking command would be `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~1 ~ ~ grass 0 scoreboard players set @p Sample_Obj 1`

comment if you have any other questions.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute

Comment: Could you make this answer a bit more general and explain a little more? As it stands, a random reader has no idea what it does, or how to change it to suit his needs.

Comment: @MrLemon done, I really should have taken more time writing this instead of rushing it.

Comment: @user3878893 This is kinda related to my "Is there a scoreboard criteria for breaking spawners?" question. Right now, I'm testing it, to make see if players can glitch it. Thanks for the help :D